# Send a dictionary where values are in a list back to an ajax request and try to parse it there

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to send a dictionary like this (values in a list):

```
datax = { "name": ["bhanu", "sivanagulu","daniel"],
             "department": ["HR", "IT", "FI"]}
```

back to an ajax request. I use two methods, it is sent, but can't unpack the content. Here are the two methods and what it looks:

1. `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(datax))`

This is what gets sent:

```
0   Object { name: […], department: […] }
name    [ "bhanu", "sivanagulu", "daniel" ]
department  [ "HR", "IT", "FI" ]
```

If I try this:

```
json_dict = json.dumps(datax)  
return JsonResponse(json_dict,safe=False)
```

I get this:

```
[{\"name\": [\"bhanu\", \"sivanagulu\", \"daniel\"], \"department\": [\"HR\", \"IT\", \"FI\"]}]"
```

in both cases, when at the client I try to parse the content,

```
obj = JSON.parse( data);
```

I get this when I try to tabulate:

```
name    [object Object] [object Object]     [object Object]
```

[this firefox console what gets sent but not parsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxzVM.png)

Comment: `return JsonResponse(datax)`

Comment: then it seems that `datax` is not a dictionary...

Comment: yes, normally that should not be a problem. Are you sure you do not assign something else to `datax` before returning the `JsonResponse`? What does `print(type(datax))` print?

Comment: I pasted a screenshot of the firefox console, the Response section.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dictionary had as keys a list, all I had to do is actually index these lists, like this when I wanted to tabulate:

```
for (const property in obj) {

      tableHTML += "<tr><td>"
      tableHTML += `${property}</td>  <td>${obj[property][0]}</td><td>${obj[property][1]}</td>\
```

and the command that worked was:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(datax))
```